# Removing out of range data from a pandas datafram (not a NaN value though)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, range

I'm using a pandas data frame to compare some weather data and some pollution levels.

I need a hand because I'm plotting some data, but one of my data points is out of range and messing with my plot.

I am using a bar plot, and I would just set the y limits of the plot, however the bar for this data point still shows up and just goes out of range.

What to do to get rid of this single value? I have tried setting it to 0 but it comes up with a warning about `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.`

here is what the plot looks like, and here is some of the code that goes with it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#defining the plot type and the data to be plotted. 
ax.bar(df1["Pressure (hPa)"].loc["2019"],
           df2["PM10 particulate matter (Hourly measured)"].loc["2019"],
           alpha=0.2,
          )

ax.bar(df1["Pressure (hPa)"].loc["2019"],
        df2["PM2.5 particulate matter (Hourly measured)"].loc["2019"],
      alpha=0.2,
      color="Green")

#setting the limits of the x axis to make the graph more readable. 
ax.set_xlim(970,1045)
```

The out of range value is in the df2. I'm just not sure how to remove it.
I have tried doing

```
df2[df2["PM2.5 particulate matter (Hourly measured)"]>150] = 0
```

but that comes up with the warning message.

I have tried using < operators too directly on the data frame, but it just gives me boolean values which I can't plot :(

Comment: Does `df2.loc[df2["PM2.5 particulate matter (Hourly measured)"]>150] = 0`  solve your problem ?

Comment: I assume you are getting a `SettingWithCopyWarning` with the solution manu190466 provided. If so, you can safely ignore that warning in this case. It is only a warning, not an error. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) for more details on that warning.

Comment: @manu190466 yes it does, but comes out with a warning, I'm just wondering if there is a better alternative...

Answer (score 0):

you can try, example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390, 1200],
  "day": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#filter:
df = df.loc[df['calories'] < 500]
sns.barplot(data=df, x="day", y="calories")
```

Comment: No because there is a shape missmatch between the two... I think I *have* to have the "space" there as it were, just with no value...